# Get FileInfo property for large numbers of files

Tags: c#

We are able to retrieve quickly `LastWriteTime`  property of a file / directory in C# form the local path even for large number of files / directories. However when the files / directories are at shared location (ex,. network driver) it took more time to retrieve the property value. We have huge number of directories and each directory has number of files in it. What would be the cause for the delay? Is there a way to optimize?

Code :

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("localpath/networkpath");
DateTime dt  = directoryInfo.LastWriteTime;
```

Comment: Retrieving data from a remote folder is a lot slower than from local disk, that's why it takes more time. I don't think there's nothing you can do unless you improve your network speed.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by obtaining the last write time for all directories and files?

Comment: The bottleneck is undoubtedly your network and not your code. If your concern is blocking you can spawn it off into a task.

Comment: FileInfo is not exactly fast, it makes an extra round-trip to the file server to get the latest and greatest property value.  If the network latency is high then that very quickly adds up.  Fixed in .NET 4.0, use EnumerateFiles/Directories() instead.